# Conflict among mymodule_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter and module_invoke

Tags: 7, views

I have, in Drupal 7, a Views which returns a list of items. The views display is a block, which I render in a section of the page. I was trying to dynamically display the block in the template using module_invoke. The block is perfectly displayed. However, if I use mymodule_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter to change the content of the block, the content is modified after the page has been processed, so Drupal still prints the unmodified version retrieved with module_invoke. I am a bit confused about the priority of events. Please advice (my goal is to have the block programmaticaly changed before displaying).